# Bearer token doesnot pass on swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, openapi, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am trying to implement OAuth2 ClientCredentials flow on ASP.NET CORE 3.1. I follow guidelines on the official GitHub repo.
The problem is regarding getting bearer token on Swagger-UI. It doesn't pass automatically. I investigated the issue on Swashbuckle Github repo. There are some closed issues. There's no solution.

Below my implementation :

```
 public static class SwaggerExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection EnableSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Sample API", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2",
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("/api/auth/token", UriKind.Relative),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { "readAccess", "Access read operations" },
                            { "writeAccess", "Access write operations" }
                        },

                        }
                    },
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }, Name = "oauth2"
                    },
                    new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" }
                }
            });

            c.OperationFilter<OAuth2OperationFilter>();
        });

        return services;
    }

 public class AuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        bool isAnonymousAllowed = context.Filters.Any(f => f.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousFilter));
        if (isAnonymousAllowed)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var authHeaderValue))
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("A valid key must be supplied");
        }

        string authHeader = authHeaderValue.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
       

       ....
    }
}
```

After creating an access_token, I cannot get this token on another controller on Swagger-UI.
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version -> 5.5.1
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger -> 5.5.1

Comment: Did you end discovering that this was issue with CORS and options preflight request?